# plantUML mindmapfixed size node

Tags: plantuml

I am trying to add a picture of the mitigation tree as shown here https://www.isograph.com/software/attacktree/mitigating-against-attacks/

I guess, plantUML has no support for verticle swimlane over mindmap. So, I tried to create a draft mitigation tree using mindmap with the following node style. The nodes are different sizes and not properly aligned. Is there any style to specify fixed width so all levels of the mindmap looks well aligned?

```
@startmindmap


<style>
node {
    Padding 12
    Margin 3
    HorizontalAlignment center
    LineColor blue
    LineThickness 3.0
    BackgroundColor gold
    RoundCorner 40
    MaximumWidth 200
}

rootNode {
    LineStyle 8.0;3.0
    LineColor red
    BackgroundColor white
    LineThickness 1.0
    RoundCorner 0
    Shadowing 0.0
}

leafNode {
    LineColor gold
    RoundCorner 0
    Padding 3
}

arrow {
    LineStyle 4
    LineThickness 0.5
    LineColor green
}
</style>

* Laptop 
** R 27
*** Admin credentials misused to create login for unauthorized
**** To be covered by ISO 27001 assessment
***** TBD
*** An adversary acquire valid credential ripping harddisk from cache shadow or password file
**** harddisk encrypted
***** CR 4.1

*** Misuse device
**** Device has MFA before authenticating inside the network
***** CR unknown
@endmindmap
```

[image: Mindmap]

The problem here is, that the node style has only a max-width attribute. So, if any text is smaller than the attributed width, the text box is going to be smaller and hence, gets unaligned.

We need an attribute like fixed-width to keep the alignment proper. Anyone knew attribute to keep the node width fixed.

Comment: If you posted more code (a MWE), I would be happy to try something.

Comment: The example with word-wrap at https://plantuml.com/mindmap-diagram#9a9f568761f736f4 seems like it could help. But you need to post more information.